# Simple differential equations not working?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

So I was trying to solve $$\sin x+\cos x=1$$ I got $\tan x + 1=\sec x$. Now let $y=\tan x$. You have $$y+1=\sqrt{y'}$$ $$dy/dx=(y+1)^2$$ $$dy/(y+1)^2=dx$$ Now integrate both sides and you get $$x+c=-1/(y+1)$$ and solving for $y$ we get $$y=-1/(x+c)-1$$ However, in the begging we said $y=\tan x$. Why is this not working? Thanks

Comment: It really helps readability to format questions using MathJax (see FAQ). Regards

Comment: Why did you try solving an algebra equation with differential equations?

Comment: I was just trying out different things to see if I can maybe discover something useful/interesting.

Comment: put all of your maths inbetween a pair of $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation $\tan x+1=\sec x$ is not generally true. It only holds for a true for a small set of points, namely the solutions $x$ to the equation $\sin x+\cos x=1$. Thus, you cannot write $y(x)=\tan x$ and say that $y(x)+1=\sec x=\sqrt{\frac{d}{dx}\tan x}=\sqrt{y'}$ holds for all $x$. You can't differentiate an equation with respect to a variable and expect to get something that's true or meaningful, when the equation only holds at a peculiar set of values in the first place. Thus, differential equations seem entirely irrelevant to this problem.

My recommendation would be to square $1=\sin x+\cos x$, then use the identity $1=\sin^2x+\cos^2x$ and the double angle formula $2\sin x\cos x=\sin(2x)$. Then the solutions should become clear.

Comment: It seems he took his equation and divided by $\cos x$

Comment: I wasn't actually trying to prove that identity, I just divided both sides by cos x and got tan x+1=sec x. But if it is true that y=tan x and it is true that sqrt(y')=sec x, why can't I substitute these and solve for y? Is it just because my equation is not an identity?

Comment: @Ovi It is not true that $\sqrt{y'}=\sec x$ holds for all $x$, because $y(x)+1=\sec x$ does not hold for all $x$. It only holds for the solutions to the original equation!

Comment: Alright thanks, it's clear now

Comment: By the way would you mind taking a look at my other question? Thanks! http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361691/what-is-the-minimum-number-of-blocks-to-build-this/361903?noredirect=1#361903